# DC.js brush to select range not working with scaleTime

Tags: javascript, dc.js

**PROLOGUE**
This is my first time posting to stackoverflow and i'm a noob with dc.js. Apologies in advance for etiquette transgressions (feedback welcome on this too)

**PROBLEM**
I have defined a barchart and it displays perfectly, but brushOn(true) is not letting me filter the data.  In the past, this seemed to work perfectly with a crosshair appearing as soon as i hovered over the bargraph. Now it is not.  Any idea why?! or what i can do to fix it? I'm on day 3 of trying to figure out what is happening.  The help is MUCH appreciated!

**PREREQS:**

```
https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js
crossfilter.min.js
https://unpkg.com/dc@3.0.4/dc.js
```

**CODE FOR BARCHART**
I have defined a barchart as follows:

```
filterDim = cross.dimension(function(d){return d3.timeWeek(d.date);});
var filterGroup = filterDim.group().reduceSum(function(d){
    if(d.isTrue){return 1;}
    else {return 0;} });

height=400;
if(width == 0){
    width = $(dom_id).parent().innerWidth();
}
var hitsbarChart  = dc.barChart(dom_id);
hitsbarChart
    .width(width).height(height)
    .dimension(sentDimension)
    .group(allGroups[0].data,allGroups[0].name)
    .xUnits(d3.timeWeeks);

hitsbarChart
    .x(d3.scaleTime())
    .valueAccessor(function(d){return d.value;})
    .keyAccessor(function(d){return d.key;})
    .round(d3.timeWeek.round)
    .yAxis().ticks(d3.format('.3s'));

    function calc_domain(chart) {
        var min = d3.min(chart.group().all(), function(kv) { return kv.key; }),
        max = d3.max(chart.group().all(), function(kv) { return kv.key; });
        max = d3.timeMonth.offset(max, 1);
        chart.x().domain([min, max]);
    }
hitsbarChart.on('preRender', calc_domain);
hitsbarChart.on('preRedraw', calc_domain);

hitsbarChart.brushOn(true);
dc.renderAll();
```

**RESEARCH**

I found [this example](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/blob/master/web/examples/switching-time-intervals.html) which demonstrates something different but outputs a graph with time-series as the x-axis and working brush to select a range of dates.

Also, there [this bug with work-around](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/issues/348) but the work around did not work. I can't imagine that time-series data works more like an ordinal scale than a numerical scale.

Comment: Should work! Indeed a time-scale is not ordinal at all. No interaction at all? No crosshair? Do you have dc.css?

Comment: Please post a fiddle if you're continuing to have trouble.

Comment: Yea, i do have dc.css.  from unpkg: https://unpkg.com/dc@3.0.4/dc.css.  I will put together a fiddle and update the question. Good to know that i didn't miss something super important/fundamental ;).

Comment: Most annoying outcome ever:  In making a fiddle, it seems to work perfectly....https://jsfiddle.net/srikasip/Lhatm67n/26/

Comment: Ha, yes you often solve the problem in the course of creating a self-contained example. It's a devious pedagogical technique. Now you just need to figure out what's different between your actual app and the fiddle :)

Comment: Hi Gordon, Thanks for all the advice and help up to now.  Do you think its possible for something that comes after the graph to be suppressing the brushing?  In my actual app, I can hover a bar and see a pointer, but if i hover anywhere else of the graph, i don't get a crosshair and clicking doesn't register anything.  If i click/filter on another part of the dashboard. Then the bargraph *does* filter and respond.  I'm really at a loss...Any ideas would be helpful.  Its definitely not the options/settings for the graph itself that is causing the problem.

Comment: It's possible that you have some CSS inadvertently affecting your chart when it was supposed to be active elsewhere in the page. I'd try looking what CSS is applied to your chart by right-clicking it's background and Inspect - see if it has `pointer-events: none` or something like that applied to it. Of course it's also possible for Javascript from another component to intrude, but it's easier to accidentally apply CSS than JS.

Comment: Success!!  Thanks for the pointer, Gordon.  I tried to inspect with no luck. Then i rebuilt the page block by block until something broke.  Turns out, the problem *was* with the CSS. After just removing blocks of classes, the problem was this.  I defined a stray class ".overlay" with display:none set. it was just around from when i was trying out different features and i wasn't actively intending on using it.  Looks like brushing reserves that class name already for displaying the cool slider thing. I never would have thought to look at the CSS. thanks! If you post the answer, i will mark it.

Comment: Lessons learned for future folks:  (1) Don't use non-specific class names. (2) Clean your code early and often.  These sounds like apple-pie and motherhood statements. I just lost 4 days of real development time and almost snapped my laptop in half in frustration because of a poorly chosen name that should have been removed anyhow.  Coding discipline has an impact. and the lack of it does too....

Comment: Thanks @Srikar, I've posted a more detailed answer based on this experience. Hopefully it will help future readers so they don't lose so much time on such frustrations!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's likely that you have some CSS inadvertently affecting your chart when it was supposed to be control some other part of the page.

This could happen either because you used a generic name which is also used by dc.js or d3.js, or because a style sheet from another library does. All of [dc.js's style rules](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/blob/develop/style/dc.scss) are carefully scoped so that they shouldn't affect anyone else, but many common words are used for class names, so interference the other way is common.

The brushing behavior comes from d3, so I'd try looking at d3's `g.brush rect.overlay` in the inspector of your developer tools. You should be able to bring it up by right-clicking the background of the chart and selecting Inspect.

If it has something like

```
pointer-events: none;
```

or

```
display: none;
```

applied to it, find out what applied that (hopefully CSS you control) and try to make the rules more specific.

Of course it's also possible for JavaScript from another library to cause such troubles, but interference from CSS is much more common.